# How can I only allow one click on my image?

Tags: javascript

I'm building a function with various eventListeners that get triggered with a click, but I want that those only get triggered once, meaning that after another click, it won't make any changes. I've tried doing `const getEffect1 = document.getElementById("specialEffect1").disabled = true` but theses are not working.

```
function clickedItems() {
      const getEffect1 = document.getElementById("specialEffect1")
      getEffect1.addEventListener("click", () => {
          effect1 = true
          var getCount = document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", () => {
            console.log(count += 1)
          })
      })
      getEffect1.onclick=""
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So remove the event with removeEventListener

```js
const getEffect1 = document.getElementById("specialEffect1");
const effectClick = () => {
  console.log('clicked');
  getEffect1.removeEventListener("click", effectClick);
};
getEffect1.addEventListener("click", effectClick);
```

```html
<div id="specialEffect1">Click</div>
```

Or using option [`once`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#parameters)

```js
const getEffect1 = document.getElementById("specialEffect1");
const effectClick = () => {
  console.log('clicked');
};
getEffect1.addEventListener("click", effectClick, { once: true });
```

```html
<div id="specialEffect1">Click</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an event.preventDefault.

```js
function clickedItems() {
      const getEffect1 = document.getElementById("specialEffect1")
      getEffect1.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
          event.preventDefault();
          effect1 = true
          var getCount = document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", () => {
            console.log(count += 1)
          })
      })
      getEffect1.onclick=""
    }
```

Comment: Should have mentioned that it's probably because something else is causing the event handler to be triggered. Ideally figure what that is and fix it. Otherwise, that should work.

Answer (score 0):

how about Changing the inner HTML of the object after detecting the first click.
so users cant submit it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `once` option to `true` in [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#parameters).

> A Boolean indicating that the listener should be invoked at most once after being added. If true, the listener would be automatically removed when invoked.

```
getEffect1.addEventListener("click", () => {
    effect1 = true;
    document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", () => {
        console.log(count += 1)
    });
}, {once: true})
```